# Why is the stop_ sound function not working using winsound and tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, winsound

```
from tkinter import *
import winsound
from winsound import PlaySound, SND_FILENAME, SND_LOOP, SND_ASYNC
root = Tk()
root.configure(background='light green')

def playing():
    PlaySound('alarm', SND_FILENAME)

def stop_sound(): 
    PlaySound(None, SND_FILENAME)

Button(root,text="playing ",font=("Helvetica 15"),command=playing).pack(pady=20)
Button(root,text="Stop",font=("Helvetica 15"),command=stop_sound).pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Since you didn't specify the `SND_ASYNC` flag when playing the sound, the GUI was locked up until the sound finished - leaving nothing to be stopped by the other button, when your click was finally accepted.

Comment: Yes it's the `SND_ASYNC`. Try `PlaySound('alarm', SND_FILENAME|SND_ASYNC)`